# remove "counter" from the end of the URL and redirect it to it's home directory with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'd like to remove /123456/ (can be any number) from the end of the url and redirect to it's home directory. The name of directory-a, b or c

redirect: http://www.mydomain.com/directory-a/directory-b/directory-c/123456/

to: http://www.mydomain.com/directory-a/directory-b/directory-c/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/[0-9]+/?$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: It is almost that I need. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/[0-9]+/?$ /$1/? [L,R=301] was the solution for me. Thank you for the "base"